# How to offer parameter for user to select an amt and then show that data

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have done report that shows summary of sales of items by free shipping or not free shipping. They are actually Product lines, that get free shipping or not.

It looks like this.

date     Invoice#      Free PL     NOt free PL   etc.

061113    1234          $29

061213    5678                             $89

They want to  have the flexibility to select ranges of BOTH free PL’s and non-free PL’s (e.g., “free PL’s over $70 and non-free over $30”, or “free PL’’s over $80 and non-free PL’s over $25” etc.)

They want to specify I guess in the param what amount then the CR should display according, so that in out case here only the second line would show.

Is this able to be done just in the param? if so, how would you code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method may be a bit lengthy but will work for you hopefully.

make a table named PL history, now give it three fields, with ID, PL_DATE and PL_RATE, you need to insert new record in to that daily. if you want it to be more finer, add another column as PL_TIME as well. now when inserting the PL_Transaction, make sure that you enter time to that table as well.

Once it is done, make a view and like the transaction table with the respective PL_DATE and PL_TIME if you incorporate time, this will ensure that you pick the right PL specified during the transaction. YOu can do it behind the generate report button, will take no time to execute.

JUst call that view to the report, and get your specific PL using the formulas,

I tried calling a field to the report mannualy, it did come to the report, but it could not be called to the formula editor so , I thought of this solution , may help. thanks